# Back button in fragment goes back to Home screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Android and fragments, so I assume I'm missing something important.
I have a main activity and 2 fragments, the second replaces the first which replaces the activity. I commit a replace transaction, not forgetting to call `addToBackStack(null)` yet for some reason each time I press the back button (from the second fragment as well) the application goes back the desktop screen and the app is available via the recent apps screen, always showing the main activity.

Why is this happening?

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
        else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MainLayout,
                new SettingsFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        return true;
    }
```

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
...
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MainLayout,
                    new SelectBackgroundFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
```

Comment: You want to move previous fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override onBackPressed in your activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```